# How can I fix the 'Source can be imported from more than one directory' error in my tsol when using Venom and Locklift?

Tags: smartcontracts, venom

Error: Source can be imported from more than one directory. venom locklift building error

I am trying to build a tsol file named Tip3Votes.tsol

but i got this error

> Error: Source "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/abstract/TokenWalletBurnableByRootBase.sol" can be imported from more than one directory.List of paths:
> /Users/sam/code/Web3/tip3-token/contracts
> /Users/sam/code/Web3/tip3-token/node_modules
>
> --> /Users/sam/code/Web3/tip3-token/contracts/Tip3Votes.tsol:2:1:
> |
> 2 | import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/abstract/TokenWalletBurnableByRootBase.sol";

Actually at first i copied tip3 folder from node_modules to my contracts folder
but when i got this error I removed the folder from my contracts folder but i'm still getting this error
I think it's save in some file but I don't know where
I removed all build and node_modules folder and again i am getting this error
what should i don to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can i see the import statements that you are using ?

Comment: yeah sure 
`import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/abstract/TokenWalletBurnableByRootBase.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/abstract/TokenWalletBurnableBase.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/abstract/TokenWalletDestroyableBase.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/libraries/TokenErrors.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/libraries/TokenGas.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/libraries/TokenMsgFlag.sol";
import "../node_modules/tip3/contracts/interfaces/IVersioned.sol";`

Comment: delete the ""../node_modules/"" part from first of your import statement